# How to roundoff the decimal places in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an expression in my report that computes the general average of a student.

```
=(((SUM(Round(Fields!FINAL_FS_GRADE.Value,0))+ SUM(Round(Fields!FINAL_SS_GRADE.Value,0)))) / CountRows("GRADES")) / 2
```

Below is sample of student Grades for Quarter 1 and Quarter 2 and final Grade

```
Q1  Q2  FINAL
83  83  83
84  83  83.5
79  80  79.5
85  88  86.5
88  88  88
84  77  80.5
83  90  86.5
82  76  79
```

If we are going to compute the general average of Final Grade, this will be 83.3125

But my requirements is to round off the final grades.

```
Q1  Q2   FINAL    ROUND OFF FINAL   
83  83   83             83  
84  83   83.5           84  
79  80   79.5           80  
85  88   86.5           87  
88  88   88             88  
84  77   80.5           81  
83  90   86.5           87  
82  76   79             79
```

So the general average will become 84.375 or 84. but my output is still 83.3

whats wrong with my expression syntax?

Thanky you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do all the work on the value, why not just leave the values as they are (no rounding) and set the format property of the field to something like `f0`. This will display 0 decimal places and round the result in the process.

Comment: Hi Alan, The final grade will automatically roundoff when I set the text properties to 0 decimal places. but If I'm going to  get all the final grades the total will be 666.5 and divide it by 8 then the General Average is 83.31 or 83 because in getting the final grades the expression will not automatically rounded the numbers. So what I'm trying to do is to roundoff the total sum of Q1 + Q2 / 8 so it will become 84 just like my example above. Thanks